# LibreOffice - Is it possible to increase the contrast between the scroll bar sliders and the scroll bar background?

Tags: libreoffice, freebsd-ports

```
FreeBSD-12.1p12
LibreOffice-7.0.3.1
```

I am finding that the scroll bar sliders, both vertical and horizontal, are coloured with a washed out grey that is nearly indistinguishable from the colour of the scroll bars themselves. Is there any way to darken either the sliders or the scroll bars so that there is a greater contrast between the two?

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice uses its own backend to handles UI called VCL (Visual Class Library). In essence, this allows the use of most if not all UI Frameworks. The scrollbars and scrollbar sliders are configured via these UI Frameworks.

###### UI Frameworks

```
UI Plugin   UI Backend
qt5         Qt 5
qt6         Qt 6
kf5         KDE KF5
gtk3        GTK 3
gtk4        GTK 4
gtk3_kde5   GTK 3 KDE 5
win         Windows UI (Windows only)
osx         macOS X UI (macOS only)
```

Above table taken from https://dev.blog.documentfoundation.org/2023/01/28/vcl-example-applications-and-tools/

##### Check for installed frameworks

First check what UI frameworks are installed, Qt5 comes with the application `qt5ct` and GTK will come with `gtk-demo`. Run these commands, whichever provides a window, you have installed. Note that both can be installed, and either configured. You may even choose which to use with the below command

`soffice -env:SAL_USE_PLUGIN=qt5`
`soffice -env:SAL_USE_PLUGIN=gtk3`
`soffice -env:SAL_USE_PLUGIN=gtk4`

We will stick with GTK for now, as it is much simpler to configure a new theme.

##### Configuring Themes in GTK

GTK themes can be readily installed from a pkg

```
❯ doas pkg search gtk
gtk-aluminumalloy-cryogenic-theme  gtk3-oxygen-engine
gtk-aluminumalloy-smog-theme       gtk3-unico-engine
gtk-aluminumalloy-toxic-theme      gtk4
gtk-aluminumalloy-volcanic-theme   gtk4-layer-shell
gtk-aquaextremesunken-theme        gtkam
gtk-arc-themes                     gtkatlantic
gtk-digital-cream-theme            gtkballs
gtk-digital-harmony-theme          gtkchtheme
gtk-doc                            gtkcord4
gtk-E17-theme                      gtkd
gtk-engines2                       gtkdatabox
gtk-equinox-engine                 gtkevemon
gtk-gnutella                       gtkextra
gtk-gray-theme                     gtkglarea
gtk-layer-shell                    gtkglext
gtk-lila-theme                     gtkglextmm
gtk-lila-theme-extras              gtkguitune
gtk-longhorninspirat-theme         gtkhtml4
gtk-milk-theme                     gtkimageview
gtk-mixer                          gtklp
gtk-murrina-aqua                   gtkmm24
gtk-murrine-engine                 gtkmm30
gtk-nodoka-engine                  gtkmmorse
gtk-oxygen-engine                  gtkpasman
gtk-pipe-viewer                    gtkperf
gtk-sharp-beans                    gtkpod
gtk-sharp20                        gtkradiant
gtk-sharp30                        gtksourceview2
gtk-theme-switch                   gtksourceview3
gtk-update-icon-cache              gtksourceview4
gtk-vnc                            gtksourceview5
gtk-xfce-engine                    gtksourceviewmm3
gtk-youtube-viewer                 gtkspell
gtk2                               gtkspell3
gtk2-qtcurve-theme                 gtkterm2
gtk3                               gtkwave
```

You can also download themes online from places such as Gnome-Look, so as to actually see what the scrollbar and slider will actually look like. :)

https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=135

If downloading from a website, you should have a `.tar.gz` file in your default download folder. To now install the theme, simply run

`tar -xvzf /path/to/theme.tar.gz`

##### Setting theme

To set a theme in GTK, you need to either create or modify `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

This is my current settings for GTK

```
[Settings]
  gtk-theme-name          = Arc
  gtk-icon-theme-name     = faenza
  gtk-font-name           = firasans 10
  gtk-cursor-theme-size   = 0
  gtk-toolbar-style       = GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
  gtk-toolbar-icon-size   = GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR
  gtk-button-images       = 1
  gtk-menu-images         = 1
  gtk-enable-event-sounds = 1
  gtk-xft-antialias       = 1
  gtk-xft-hinting         = 1
  gtk-xft-hintstyle       = hintnone
  gtk-xft-rgba            = rgb
```

For more information around configuration options, consult the Docs.

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Settings.html

I hope this helps and fixes the scrollbar visibility. :)